# Fused Location provides less frequent updates on Oreo even in foreground

Tags: android, foreground, android-8.0-oreo, fusedlocationproviderapi

Till Android < 8 I got location updates according to the interval passed to the locationRequest (more or less 4 seconds); on devices running Oreo, even if this is a foreground service,  the updates are less frequent (30-60 seconds).

Long story short, this is the relevant code of my foreground service:

```
public void onCreate() {

        mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

        mLocationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
                super.onLocationResult(locationResult);
                onNewLocation(locationResult.getLastLocation());
            }
        };

        createLocationRequest();

        HandlerThread handlerThread = new HandlerThread(TAG);
        handlerThread.start();
        mServiceHandler = new Handler(handlerThread.getLooper());
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    }

public void requestLocationUpdates() {

        Log.d(TAG, "Requesting location updates");
        isServiceRunning = true;
        getLastLocation();

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

            startForegroundService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LocationVeloxService.class));

        }
        else {

            startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LocationVeloxService.class));
        }
        startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, getNotification(false));

        try {

            mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, mLocationCallback, Looper.myLooper());
        }
        catch (SecurityException unlikely) {

            isServiceRunning = false;
            Log.e(TAG, "Lost location permission. Could not request updates. " + unlikely);
        }
    }

private void createLocationRequest() {
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    }
```

I need very frequent position updates otherwise my app is useless...

Any advice?
Thanks

Comment: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/background-location-updates-android-o/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#6

Comment: @JaiminSarvan could you elaborate? I'm already using a foreground service...